# Maximize size of figure such as to maintain page breaks

Tags: floats, page-breaking, size

In this MWE, I manually fine-tuned the width of the graphics (`0.711082\linewidth`) in order to maximize its size while fitting the whole document on one page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.711082\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

Is there any general mechanism to achieve something like this?

Comment: is your real document only one page?

Comment: No, the real document is more complex. But I can think of a variety of criteria to judge when a figure is "too big" - number of pages, some page having excessive white space, a section not beginning at the top of a page, stuff like that. My question is really geared towards learning about such mechanisms, not just a solution to one simple example.

Comment: If you know where you want the image to go, you can scale it to fit the remaining page.  If you put it into a float, you have no idea where it will actually show up.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of scaling an image to fit the remaining page...  (Needs to run twice.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength{\maxheight}

\newcommand{\maxgraphics}[1]% #1 = filename
{\settoheight{\maxheight}{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{#1}}%
 \tikz[remember picture]{% measuer distance to bottom of page
   \dimendef\y=0% local definition
   \pgfextracty{\y}{\pgfpointanchor{current page text area}{south}}%
   \ifdim\y>-1pt \y=-1pt\fi
   \ifdim\maxheight>-\y
     \global\maxheight=-\y
   \fi}\par\vspace{-\parskip}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vfill% not on same baseline
 \includegraphics[height=\maxheight]{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \begin{center}
      \maxgraphics{example-image}
    \end{center}
    \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```