# Define text box so that it consumes the rest of the page

Tags: spacing

I have several images stacked on top of each other for a title page.  An MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[paper = letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{margin = 0in}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width = \paperwidth, height = 4.4cm, keepaspectratio]{example-image}

    \hbox{
    \hspace{12em}
    \includegraphics[height = 4cm]{example-image}
    }

\pgfpicture
    \pgftext{\includegraphics[width = \paperwidth, height = 18.cm]{example-image}}
    \pgftext[right]{
        \parbox[t][0ex][l]{9.5cm}{\begin{tabular}[t]{p{12cm}}
        {\Huge \color{red} \bfseries Title!}\\
        \\
        \\
        {\Large \color{red} {Author!\newline Address! \newline City!  State!  ZIP!}}\\
        \end{tabular}}
    }
\endpgfpicture

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor = black]
{\fontfamily{times}\selectfont{\Large \color{white} \textbf Company tag line here}}
\end{mdframed}
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

[image]

I want the final box to automatically be sized such that it fills the rest of the page.  How can I do that?  I've found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/how-to-define-a-figure-size-so-that-it-consumes-the-rest-of-a-page) but this is image specific rather than text-box specific, and I'm finding it hard to generalize.

Specific questions:

**1.** How can I insert a text box with black background and vertically-centered white text that automatically fills the rest of the page?

**2.** How can I make the text in that box align with the title and author text above?  I suspect I could just trial and error with `\hspace{*X*em}` until it lines up.  I don't know if this could be automatic.

Alternatives to the `mdframed` package are welcome.

Comment: The answer you're citing seems to be well in line with what you're looking for, have you tried to implement it ?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307504/maximize-size-of-figure-such-as-to-maintain-page-breaks/307529?s=2|0.0000#307529 also shows how to determine the remaining space.   I don't know about mdframed, but you can always use \fbox{\parbox[c][\dimexpr \maxheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule][c]{\dimexpr \textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{...}}